# Temperature does not drop to the set thermostat during the day

Tags: hvac

I just bought a house. I have a HVAC from 2021 that, per my handyman, is more than sufficient for my house size (1700SF). I live in GA where the current temps are 85-100°F regularly and in the mid 70s at night.

I set my thermostat to 73° 24/7 to test it out and during the day, the temp will creep up to 75-79° but when I wake up in the morning it will be at 73°. If I set it 73 when I get back from home (3:30pm) and 78 during the day, then it just ends up being like 77 or so by the time I go to bed and 73 when I wake up.

Also, I noticed that certain rooms have a noticeable, strong blast of cold air while other rooms, I can barely even feel that the air coming out. I have no idea what my electric bill should be but it seems high (195$). I control the amount of natural light entering my house pretty well.

During my home inspection, the inspector mentioned that there was minor amount of insulation falling out into the crawlspace and that the main HVAC trunk look liked it was slightly obstructed (i.e. someone might have stepped on it in the crawlspace). I'm thinking either the obstruction is causing the issue, there is a tear I am not aware of, that damper thing that you can rotate to control airflow to different rooms (I assume I have that), or something is messed up with the coils/ac unit?

But I have no experience with any of this so I am just guessing. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using an eco-thermostat?

Answer (score 7):

$200 electric bills for June/July in Atlanta is not high. The best way to get a sense of what is normal there is to ask your neighbors.

If the airflow feels uneven, that would cause rooms to have significantly different temperatures. It would not cause the system to not cool effectively.

First step as a homeowner is to change the filters. There is not much else an untrained or inexperienced DIY'er can do to an AC system other that cleaning out the drain line. During cooling season, you should be changing your filters at least once a month. Start with the cheap filters. They may not be as effective at cleaning the air as an expensive super filter, but they do not restrict the airflow as much. By using cheap filters, you get maximum airflow. If that solves your cooling problem, then you can try other filters if you desire the additional cleaning properties. But be prepared to switch back if you lose cooling performance again.

If you trust your handyman, ask him for a referral to an HVAC professional. If you didn't have the system inspected and tested during closing, you're already overdue for a check-up.

Comment: Good idea. I will ask my neighbors. I change the filters monthly. I will tak e alook at the drain line this weekend

Comment: Are people in the USA paying $200 electric bills for heating and cooling? Goodness. Over here in Germany we live in smaller apartments and they don't cost nearly that much, even with the very high electricity prices.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, Americans use significantly more electricity. According to [this article](https://shrinkthatfootprint.com/average-household-electricity-consumption/), the average annual consumption is about 11MWh for US households, vs a bit over 3MWh for German households.

Answer (score 7):

> I have a HVAC from 2021 that, per my handyman, is more than sufficient
> for my house size (1700SF).

Your handyman is assuming a level of insulation that your house does not meet. This is the problem with "square foot to BTU" rules of thumb - they make a lot of assumptions, and can be wrong in either direction.

You need more insulation, (which costs money once when you buy it) or more AC capacity (which costs more to buy and costs more to run.) Thus, I would recommend addressing the insulation rather than increasing the system size.

You can also check over basic things like "clean filters" and "gently hose out the condenser fins without bending them" that might impact your system working as it should, but a 2021 system ought to be in fairly good shape. Of course, if it does have leaks from damages, those would negatively impact performance.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what the other answers say, I'd definitely suggest looking at the exhaust vents in each room. Most of the time these are louvered with an adjustment lever, what you called a damper.

You may need to change how these are adjusted per room so the airflow is more evenly distributed. Rooms closer to the HVAC will likely have higher pressure at the vent so can be closed some, which will also increase air pressure in vents along the same duct. Rooms that are farther away from the HVAC will likely need to be opened some, if not all the way.

You may never get the whole house perfectly balanced, but you should be able to reduce the "blast" in some rooms and increase the trickle in others. And yes, these can determine how well the house is cooled. If one room is cooled "too much" compared to another and is right next to the thermostat, the thermostat will only cool until "the cold room" is the correct temp, leaving the rest of the house hot. And the opposite can happen, where the thermostat is in the "hot room" and refrigerates the rest of the house. Neither situation is good.

My own house has poor circulation, just in general. I had to adjust those room vents, too. I also had to cut in room-to-hallway passthrough vents so there is still circulation when the doors were closed.

I use a box fan at the top of the stairs to blow hot air down. There's an air intake/"cold air return" at the the top of the stairs, but it doesn't work well enough. I've added a baffle in the air intake system to try to make sure air was being pulled from the upstairs. That helped a lot, but not enough. You may end up needing a baffle in your system, since the air intake for the HVAC supposed to help circulate air through your rooms.

Another problem in my house is a vaulted entryway and living room combo, which takes up about 40% of the first floor. This is also the main exhaust for the HVAC system. It basically dumps air into the room in one spot halfway to the ceiling with the hope that the air intake in the kitchen will draw air around 2 corners enough to circulate the cold air across the whole room. Because that doesn't work very well, I have another box fan blowing across the room and through the tiny hallway that leads to the kitchen.

That little hallway also houses my thermostat. I'm thinking that the warmer air from the big room blows across the thermostat so the HVAC knows it needs to run a little more, which obviously also help cool the house.

Neither of these box fans are good solutions, but they are better than nothing. They improve the circulation considerably which keeps the house much cooler. You may have to resort to something like that until you can find better solutions. I know I'm still looking for something better, like adding ceiling fans to the big room.

You may need to look at your windows, too. If you don't have blinds, curtains, or another way to block out the sun, you may be letting in a lot of heat. This is particularly important if you don't have good/large trees around your house to block some of the sun from hitting your house. Some newer windows have a treatment/additive to the glass that blocks UV and/or IR, helping to keep your house cooler and preventing things from getting sun bleached. But most houses don't have that.

My windows don't have it, I don't have trees to block the sun, and my blinds weren't enough, so I had to go with a somewhat expensive route and add a dark, mirror-like plastic film to the windows to block out UV, IR, and visible light. It comes in rolls and can often be found in home improvement stores. You cut it to size and shape, and then spray some applicator fluid on the window, then use a squeegee like thing to press out the air bubbles. Make sure the follow the directions, since each brand is likely different. The stuff I got had a clear plastic backing to it that I had to peel off as I applied it to reveal adhesive. I didn't do it for the first window, so it just immediately fell off.

It took me months to do it, but I've applied the same treatment to all my windows. I used the stuff that only allows 10% transmission. It makes the house darker and will kill/starve your indoor plants, but it helps tremendously with heat. My windows used to too hot to touch, which I'm sure radiated off a whole lot of heat, but now they are just warm.

Something else to look at are the roof, eaves, and gable vents. If they are clogged/covered or don't exist, your attic spaces may be getting too hot and transferring that heat to the living spaces. (Not having them can also trap moisture, causing mold, which is a different problem.) This, along with adding more insulation, might be a spring or fall project, though. Some vents might require a fan, but that would be something to talk to your handyman about.

One thing that also seems to have helped is a patio roof. I added it to keep the sun off the patio, but it also keeps the sun off about 1/3rd of the south facing wall of my house, several windows, the back door, and even my HVAC compressor unit (in the late afternoon and evening).

Besides just adding more insulation to your attic/roof space, you might need to have someone come to your house for an air leak or similar inspection. Depending on how they do it, they might use a FLIR camera to see where heat is leaking into and out of your house. The walls around your doors and windows might not have enough insulation from when they were installed. Fixing that can be expensive, since you have to tear out drywall, but it's also something to think about. I'd say this is one of the "last resort" options, though, since it's probably (hopefully) not a major problem, but it can be a major project to fix these issues.

This inspection would also show if your doors and windows aren't sealing correctly, you can also be leaking heat that way, too. Sometimes replacing seals is all that's required to fix those problems, but sometimes you need to replace the whole window or door, so again, not necessarily a quick/cheap/easy fix.

FYI, I live in Las Vegas, NV, which is seeing temperatures over 110F regularly the past 2-3 weeks. Yesterday my Nest said it was 114F outside. My (cheap Chinese) outdoor wireless thermometer often reads 122F, and it's in the shade. (The highest I've seen is 126F this past week. That thermometer also says it's +100F outside by 9am.) I set my thermostat at 82F and have a ceiling fan running on high above me at any given time. So while I'm not an expert at HVAC or air circulation, I do have some experience battling heat and getting the house to a reasonable (for me) temperature.

Good luck and stay hydrated!